# How can I display all the react material table row instead of 10?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using `MaterialDatatable` only 10 row is displaying at a time I want to display all the rows at a time.

NPM Demo Url : https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-datatable

I tried `rowsPerPage` but there I'm not able to define all the table rows.

My code:-

```js
             <MaterialDatatable
                title="My Team"
                data={data}
                columns={columns}
                options={{rowsPerPage:50 }}
               />
```

Comment: The easiest thing to do is i think have rowsPerPage  an extremely large number you know will always be larger than your data and have the pagination disabled. Something like that
const options = {
      rowsPerPage: 10000,
      pagination: false
    };

Comment: this is not solution...